# How many distinct sets can be formed if each element can be present in at max r sets?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

A set of subsets of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is to be created in the following way : for a certain integer $r$ such that $n \geq r$,

- Each element of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ can be present in at most $r$ sets.
- The ***size of each subset is also equal to $r$***.

How can one find such a collection of sets which has the largest size? Please note that I am taking **$n \geq r$**.

*Example*  : Take $\{1,2,3,4\}$ (i.e. $n=4$) and each element can be present in at most $2$ sets so that $r=2$. We obtain $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}$ as the answer.

I don't know how to generalize this to larger $n$ and $r$.

Please tell me how to approach this.

---

I did this using graph theory approach. But I was not sure of the exact number of sets. I defined a bipartite graph with left side as 1 to n with degree almost r and right side vertices of graph as some s with degree r. This gave me $nr\geq sr \implies s \leq n$. But I was thinking of a certain number. ***Is there any possible relation between s and $r^2$ is what I was looking for!** Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest possible number of sets is $n$. This can be obtained by taking the $n$ cyclic rotations of the set $\{1,\dots,r\}$.

This is best explained with an example. When $n=8$ and $r=5$, here is a collection of $8$ subsets, each with size $5$, such that every element appears in at most $5$ subsets.
$$
\{1,2,3,4,5\}\\
\{2,3,4,5,6\}\\
\{3,4,5,6,7\}\\
\{4,5,6,7,8\}\\
\{5,6,7,8,1\}\\
\{6,7,8,1,2\}\\
\{7,8,1,2,3\}\\
\{8,1,2,3,4\}\\
$$
It should be clear that $n$ subsets is the best possible number. If you have $s$ subsets each with size $r$, then the total number of elements in all subsets, counted with repeats, is $r\cdot s$. On average, that means each element of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ appears in $r\cdot s/n$ subsets. Since we require each element to appear in at most $r$ subsets, this average must be at most $r$, which implies $r\cdot s/n\le r$, which implies $s\le n$.

Comment: sir I did this using graph theory approach. But I was not sure of the exact number of sets. I defined a bipartite graph with left side as 1 to n with degree almost r and right side vertices of graph as some s with degree r. This gave me $nr \geq sr \implies s \leq n$. But I was thinking of a certain number. ***Is there any possible relation between s and $r^2$ is what I was looking for**! Any thoughts?

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, $r^2$ is unrelated to this problem.

Comment: thank you......!